# Attempting to create a table through docker with .sh file

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

Using 
VSCode 
Windows 10 
Docker 18.09

Ultimately im trying to create tables in a database for my project. 
However im starting by just trying to have a script create a database with user and password. The first time I ran it it gave me an error that i fixed. Since then i haven't seen any output from the script that I expect. Im still new to docker and shell scripting so it may just be a foolish error.

yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build: ./literate-app
    command: nodemon -e vue,js,css start.js
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - literate-net
  server:
    build: ./readability-server
    command: nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:5555 server.js
    networks:
      - literate-net
  redis_db:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
      - literate-net
  postgres:
    restart: 'always'
    #image: 'bitnami/postgresql:latest'
    #volumes:
     #- /bitnami
     # - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - literate-net
    environment:
      - "FILLA_DB_USER=my_user"
      - "FILLA_DB_PASSWORD=password123"
      - "FILLA_DB_DATABASE=my_database"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password123"
      #- "POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=my_user"
      #- POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password123
      #- POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=my_database
    build: './database-creation'

networks:
  literate-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile in database-creation

```
FROM postgres:latest
COPY ./init /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

.sh file in init folder

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exits immediately if any errors occur
set -o errexit

#Array containing enviornment variables
# variable expansion ${REQUIRED_ENV_VARS[@]}
readonly REQUIRED_ENV_VARS=(
    "FILLA_DB_USER"
    "FILLA_DB_PASSWORD"
    "FILLA_DB_DATABASE"
    "POSTGRES_USER"
)

#MAIN
# - verifies all env vars set
# - rusn SQL code to create user and DB
main() {
    echo "running main"
    check_env_vars_set
    init_user_and_db
}

#check all required env vars set
#echos texting explaining which arent set
#and the name of the ones that need to be
check_env_vars_set() {
    for required_env_var in ${REQUIRED_ENV_VARS[@]}; do 
        if [[ -z "${!required_env_var}"]]; then
            echo "ERROR: 
            Enviornment variable '$required_env_var' not set. 
            Make sure you have the following enviornment varaibles set:

            ${REQUIRED_ENV_VARS[@]}

            Aborting."

            exit 1
        fi 
    done
}

# Initializes already started PostgreSQL
# uses preconfigured POSTGRES_USER user
init_user_and_db() {
    echo "Running init user"
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE USER $FILLA_DB_USER WITH PASSWORD 'FILLA_DB_PASSWORD';
        CREATE DATABASE $FILLA_DB_DATABASE;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $FILLA_DB_DATABASE TO $FILLA_DB_USER;
EOSQL
}

# Runs main routing with env vars passed through command line
main"$@"
```

Output of docker-compose build

```
PS C:\Users\rluth\Documents\CS481\literate-webapp> docker-compose build
redis_db uses an image, skipping
Building webapp
Step 1/9 : FROM node:carbon
 ---> 1f6c34f7921c
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c605a573cd99
Step 3/9 : RUN npm install -g nodemon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6c1c28e4f182
Step 4/9 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3bb6a4b324a8
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bc8fd6398f03
Step 6/9 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 97c0e2897b40
Step 7/9 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db0a36307e3d
Step 8/9 : ENV READABILITY_HOST=server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d35888e03537
Step 9/9 : CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6d8a2f33b636
Successfully built 6d8a2f33b636
Successfully tagged literate-webapp_webapp:latest
Building server
Step 1/9 : FROM node:carbon
 ---> 1f6c34f7921c
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c605a573cd99
Step 3/9 : RUN npm install -g nodemon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6c1c28e4f182
Step 4/9 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2aaedaad714c
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 95b29f636426
Step 6/9 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 257f6fdb4342
Step 7/9 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8fedcbbaeaf
Step 8/9 : ENV REDIS_HOST=redis_db
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 88cc24988b0a
Step 9/9 : CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
 ---> 6161eb6fc7b8
Successfully built 6161eb6fc7b8
Successfully tagged literate-webapp_server:latest
Building postgres
Step 1/2 : FROM postgres:latest
 ---> f97a959a7d9c
Step 2/2 : COPY ./init /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
 ---> 216e193c384b
Successfully built 216e193c384b
Successfully tagged literate-webapp_postgres:latest
```

Output from docker-compose up

```
PS C:\Users\rluth\Documents\CS481\literate-webapp> docker-compose up
Recreating literate-webapp_postgres_1 ... done
Starting literate-webapp_redis_db_1   ... done
Starting literate-webapp_server_1     ... done
Starting literate-webapp_webapp_1     ... done
Attaching to literate-webapp_webapp_1, literate-webapp_server_1, literate-webapp_redis_db_1, literate-webapp_postgres_1
webapp_1    | [nodemon] 1.18.9
webapp_1    | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
webapp_1    | [nodemon] watching: *.*
webapp_1    | [nodemon] starting `node start.js`
server_1    | [nodemon] 1.18.9
server_1    | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
server_1    | [nodemon] watching: *.*
server_1    | [nodemon] starting `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:5555 server.js`
server_1    | Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:5555/7a2352e1-7048-4cd1-8b4e-59f29e5d3263
server_1    | For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
redis_db_1  | 1:C 08 Mar 2019 19:28:25.367 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_db_1  | 1:C 08 Mar 2019 19:28:25.367 # Redis version=5.0.3, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_db_1  | 1:C 08 Mar 2019 19:28:25.367 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis_db_1  | 1:M 08 Mar 2019 19:28:25.368 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_db_1  | 1:M 08 Mar 2019 19:28:25.369 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis_db_1  | 1:M 08 Mar 2019 19:28:25.369 # Server initialized
redis_db_1  | 1:M 08 Mar 2019 19:28:25.369 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with
Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
redis_db_1  | 1:M 08 Mar 2019 19:28:25.369 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis_db_1  | 1:M 08 Mar 2019 19:28:25.369 * Ready to accept connections
postgres_1  | 2019-03-08 19:28:26.040 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2019-03-08 19:28:26.041 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2019-03-08 19:28:26.064 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2019-03-08 19:28:26.100 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-03-08 19:23:29 UTC
postgres_1  | 2019-03-08 19:28:26.681 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
postgres_1  | 2019-03-08 19:28:26.689 UTC [23] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1651400
postgres_1  | 2019-03-08 19:28:26.689 UTC [23] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1651438: wanted 24, got 0
postgres_1  | 2019-03-08 19:28:26.690 UTC [23] LOG:  redo done at 0/1651400
postgres_1  | 2019-03-08 19:28:26.748 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
server_1    | Master 18 is running
server_1    | Readability API server started on: 5000
server_1    | ESTABLISHED CONNECTION WITH REDIS SERVER!
server_1    | Caching enabled.
server_1    | Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:5556/ff7a4ef9-3680-409b-893e-fc8401db16e5
server_1    | For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
server_1    | Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:5557/dead55a8-7f1e-4e4b-8f78-ad1c03c26cc3
server_1    | For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
webapp_1    | LITERATE app listening on port 3000
```

It does create the postgres container. However checking the priveleges and databases in that container lead me to believe that my script isnt properly being ran.

output for postgres databases

```
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

Roles of postgres

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

So my question is how can i check what exactly the docker is doing would be useful. And the more pressing question is what am I doing wrong or what am I missing that is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer here.

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/203#issuecomment-255200501

Heres the gist of what happened to cause this issue.

Yeah, the problem is not the existing images on your host, but it stems from the volume (or bind mount directory) being already initialized after your first start. The postgres user, and database creation only happens on the first start (ie, /var/lib/postgresql/data must not already contain database files).

From yosifkit from the link i posted above.

To solve this either call

```
docker-compose rm -fv
```

this empties all containers and volumes ( good if you dont have a super big system)

or you can call

```
docker-compose rm -fv postgres
```

(postgres in my case. Depends what you call the title for the build in the yml file. This is good for just removing that container and its volumes.)

Comment: Also be sure to make sure your files are in UNIX format. I was using VScode and had to change my .sh file to use LF end of line sequence instead of CRLF